# Как оптимизировать алгоритм решения задачи на JavaScript

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, оптимизация, производительность, битовые-операции

Задача:

> Все числа в несортированном массиве присутствуют дважды, кроме того, который вы должны найти. Числа всегда являются допустимыми целыми значениями от 1 до 2147483647, поэтому нет необходимости в проверке типа и ошибок. Массив содержит по крайней мере одно число и может содержать миллионы чисел. Поэтому убедитесь, что ваше решение оптимизировано для скорости.
>   Пример: при входных данных [ 1, 8, 4, 4, 6, 1, 8 ] должен быть ответ 6.

Я ее решил двумя способами:

1. медленный с двумя циклами:

```js
function findUnique(numbers) {
  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
      if (numbers[i] == numbers[j] && i != j) break;
    }
    if (j == numbers.length) return numbers[i];
  }
}

console.log(findUnique([1, 8, 4, 4, 6, 1, 8]));
```

2. он намного быстрее, но тоже не проходит тест на скорость работы

```js
function findUnique(numbers) {
  numbers.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  });
  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i += 2) {
    if (numbers[i] != numbers[i + 1]) return numbers[i];
  }
}

console.log(findUnique([1, 8, 4, 4, 6, 1, 8]));
```

Как можно решить задачу еще быстрее?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Судя по полученной из Интернета информации, в JS есть оператор побитового исключающего или - `^`.

Примените его ко всем числам подряд и получите искомое число, имеющееся в одном экземпляре...

Могу ошибаться при написании кода, но что-то типа

```js
function findUnique(numbers) {
  var res = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    res = res ^ numbers[i];
  }
  return res;
}
console.log(findUnique([1, 8, 4, 4, 6, 1, 8]));
```

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/ece515h6(v=vs.84)

Comment: я только одно не понял что делает этот побитовый оператор конкретно в вашем примере?

Comment: @Demon__ANT Выбирает нужное значение :)

Comment: @Harry очень доходчиво спасибо =(

Comment: Спасибо! Это решение прошло тест по скорости! Хотя я тоже не совсем понял как оно работает.

Comment: @Demon__ANT Да все просто. `a ^ b ^ b` равно `a`. А `a ^ 0` тоже равно `a`. Просто каждая пара чисел нейтрализует сама себя - ну распишите пару действий побитово, что тут сложного?...

Comment: @Harry спасибо.Немного сложно то есть в примере было не так а вы в комментарии объяснили доходчиво.

Answer (score 3):

Можно оптимизировать решение @Harry на JavaScript в одну строку:

```js
function findUnique(numbers) {
  return numbers.reduce((a, b) => a ^ b);
}

console.log(findUnique([ 1, 8, 4, 4, 6, 1, 8 ]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил провести небольшой тест **для наглядности** и **из любопытства**. Данный ответ не является ответом, но размещать в комментариях, по моему, дикость... По поводу заполнения массива сильно не пинайте, в js слабоват.

Итак:

```
// Формируем массив
let arr = new Array;
for(let i = 1; i < 25000; i++){
    arr.push(i + 1);
    arr.push(i);
    arr.push(i - 1);
}

// Добиваем до 75К
arr.push(0);
arr.push(25000);

// Добавляем уникальное значение
arr.push(25001);

// Рандомизируем
arr.sort();

// Тестируем
const start = new Date().getTime();
console.log(findUnique(arr));
const end = new Date().getTime();
console.log(end - start + 'ms');
```

Итоги (здесь А - медленная функция ТС, B - быстрая функция ТС, C - ответ от @Harry)

```
A: 646ms - 834ms (ответ 25001 - правильный)
B: 7ms - 11ms (ответ 2)
C: 1ms - 2ms (ответ 15)
```

То ли я дурак, то ли лыжи не едут...

Comment: У Вас в массиве многие числа (например, 2) встречаются по три раза. Медленная функция ищет и находит уникальное число (25001), быстрая ищет минимальное число, которое встречается нечетное число раз (2), ответ Harry рассчитывает на то, что все неуникальные числа будут встречаться ровно два раза, поэтому получается мусор (xor всех чисел, которые встречаются нечетное число раз).

Comment: С корректно заполненным (по условию) массивом все функции возвращают одинаковый результат: https://playcode.io/372155

Comment: @defaultlocale принято, понято, спасибо))